# How to display remote images on iOS simulator

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to show and image downloaded from web in a Xamarin.Forms app.
I'm simply binding the URL to the Source property of Image. In Android simulator this works perfectly, but in iOS the image is not showing.
This is the XAML:

```
<Image Source="{Binding HomeTeamLogo, Source={x:Reference this}}" HeightRequest="80" WidthRequest="80" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
```

I tried also to load the image by binding it to and ImageSource backing property. 
The URL is in HTTPS, but also the web services I'm calling are in HTTPS, so it's not a certificate related issue.
Xamarin seems to be updated to latest version:

```
Xamarin.iOS
Version: 13.16.0.13 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: b75deaf82
Branch: d16-5-xcode11.4
Build date: 2020-04-01 21:33:19-0400
```

Is there any simulator configuration I can check? In the past days I downloaded a sample app from Microsoft which was loading images from web, obtaining the same result: no images where show in iOS simulator, Android simulator working perfectly.

Comment: Have you tried my solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change your HttpClient implementation, sometimes it works better with different TLS version support.

Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/http-stack) for more informations.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a try with the latest Xamarin.forms version **4.6.0.726**. I just wrote a demo and test the binding remote image, it works well on my side.

I use the code :

```
<Image Source="{Binding DateTime}" HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
```

and here is my [test image url](https://placekitten.com/g/1000/1000).

If you can share your image url here, I will test it on my side.

I also upload my sample project [here](https://github.com/XfHua/remote-image-binding) and you can have a try with your url. Let me know if it works.